# How can I download file from web using python? (without url)

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm a newbie trying to extract files from this web page http://www.cnmv.es/ipps/ (Spanish companies information)

The problem is that I have to fill first a few fields (company, semester, year) and then click on download. Using the browser, it starts a download of a .zip file that contains one or more .xbrl files, but I can't find a way to do it in python via requests or similar (there is no URL in the download button), getting the file content to a variable and save a file in a path.

What I tried is what I could find in the web about similar issues, I read something about ajax, json, beautifulsoup... but no results. My actual script is wrong because the only thing I get is the response but not the target file, and I need your help, please.

Here you can find a draft of what i have in mind, this is similar to my actual script.

```
from requests import Session

s = Session()

Company = [''] #Companies string array
Semester = [''] #Semester string array
Year = [''] #Years string array

for x in range(Company):
    for y in range(Semester):
        for z in range(Year):
            
            #request the data and receive the desired information
            response = s.post(
                url='http://www.cnmv.es/ipps/',
                data = {
                    'wDescargas$drpEntidades': Company[x], #search parameters
                    'wDescargas$drpPeriodos': Semester[y],
                    'wDescargas$drpEjercicios': Year[z])
                },

                headers={
                    'Referer': 'http://www.cnmv.es/ipps/',
                }
            )

            #save the content of the target file in a path

            data = response.content
            filename = Semester[y] + Company[x] + Year[z]

            with open(filename,'w+b') as s:
                s.write(data)
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the selenium package in Python3 to automate the whole process because that site is using the .NET framework and there are a lot of POST values other than 'wDescargas$drpEntidades', 'wDescargas$drpPeriodos', 'wDescargas$drpEjercicios'...

Just check the source code of that website and you'll understand why using requests package is not a good choice here...

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="./" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Priyam Harsh, I managed to do it with selenium :)